# How to combine bold and "code sample" in Markdown?

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting

How can I make a word in a code sample bold? I only see asterisks around the expected bold text.

```
sample **sample** sample
```

Comment: You are not quoting, you are formatting the text as code / preformatted.

Comment: Re: your edit, there is no way to use markdown formatting inside code samples. By definition, content in code samples is rendered verbatim.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Use `<pre>` formatting and HTML tags.

```
<pre>
sample <b>sample</b> sample
</pre>
```

Gives:

```
sample sample sample
```

---

Since you can use other HTML tags as well, this is nice for including inline documentation for commands or classes, etc.:

```
<pre>
<i><a href="http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/prename.1.html">rename</a></i> ’s/\.bak$//’ *.bak
</pre>
```

Gives:

```
rename 's/\.bak$//' *.bak
```

But, with any formatting tricks, please don't overdo it.

Comment: I'm noticing that if the underlying code would overfill the page, instead of automatically making a horizontally scrolling box, the `<pre>` approach just pushes to a second line and ruins the formatting. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I think that still, if you're copypasting that code, the line breaks would be correct.

Comment: well, the line breaks are respected..  just that there's too many of them

Comment: I cannot get this to work on sites that accept code without getting the "improperly formatted code" error. I even get it if use <pre><code> instead.

Comment: I assume there is no way of doing this if the code sample actually is html. In that case, is there any other option?

Comment: @OttoAbnormalverbraucher Not that I am aware of, no.

Comment: It's worth checking how your Markdown parser converts normal code to HTML (the easiest way is the right-click "inspect" in your browser).  For instance, some parsers use `<span class="pre">` instead of `<code>`, and some parsers add additional CSS classes to `<pre>`. If you don't match what the parser produces, the formatting of the code may be different than normal backtick code.

Comment: I get the following error on stackoverflow when trying to use that technique: "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.". And that prevents me from posting an answer.

Answer (score 43):

**Disclaimer**: I do not condone this, I'm just pointing out a possibility (for the sake of completion)

## Markdown-only hack

The basic idea is to apply bold/italic formatting to backtick-enclosed string (instead of applying *within* the backticks), then put the code spans side by side so that they render as a single code span.

### Formatting (bold and italic) in emulated code block

Huge drawback: no syntax highlighting

1. Bold formatting

   ```
   > `sample`**`sample`**`sample`
   ```

   outputs as:

   > `sample`**`sample`**`sample`
2. Italics formatting

   ```
   > *`rename`*`'s/\.bak$//' *.bak`
   ```

   outputs as:

   > *`rename`*`'s/\.bak$//' *.bak`

### Formatting in code span

1. Bold formatting

   ```
   `one`**`two`**`three`
   ```

   outputs as

   `one`**`two`**`three`
2. Bold and italics side by side

   ```
   `one`**`two`**&#07;*`three`*
   ```

   outputs as

   `one`**`two`***`three`*

   You need a non-printing character or a zero-width character (e.g. zero width space `&#8203;`) to separate the markdown for bold and markdown for italics.

### Drawback

1. Hackish, clumsy and unsightly (way less readable than its [HTML counterpart](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183613/225020))
2. The emulated code block cannot be syntax highlighted compared to a real code block
3. When you line up two code spans (with different formatting) side by side, there is always a space in between.

   So it's not possible to apply say bold formatting to a string within double quotes like `print "Hello world";` without a space between the string and quotes.

   ```
   `print "`**`Hello world`**`";`
   ```

   would render as

   `print "`**`Hello world`**`";`
4. Others (left as exercise to the reader)

Comment: But how would you do this for code blocks (as opposed to inline code)?

Comment: @Pacerier You could use the emulated code block (but I think it's going to be ugly if the site you're using has different background colors for code span and blockquotes)

Comment: But if you mean something that uses markdown's code block, I don't think that's possible

Answer (score 10):

Make it an actual quote instead of a code fragment, by prefixing the text with `>` instead of four spaces.

The following markdown:

```
> sample **sample** sample
```

Gives:

> sample **sample** sample

Comment: But then it's not code anymore…

Comment: Yup, the question was originally about quotes, not code samples.

Comment: Original question: "How can I make a word in a code sample bold?"

Comment: @flamewave000: Original question: "How can I make a word in a quoted text bold?" The "code sample" part was edited in after this answer was posted.