# Strong, bold, and backtick not working when trying to style a text piece

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, code-block

Please, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29691496/751796) post in SO. I've tried to make some part of the text bold to make the change noticeable. But it doesn't make it bold, instead it just adds leading and trailing `**`. Here, in meta, it works. Is there something I need to tune in stackoverflow? I've had this problem for at least 3 days.

Here I'm sending you the snapshot in case there's no problem when you view the post.[image: snapshot]

Comment: None of the SE sites allow markup *within a code block*, not just SO. I think this is [tag:status-by-design].

Comment: Haaaaa, now I get, it. So this is because I'm inside a code block. Ok, I get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Markdown doesn't support text markup inside a code block. A code block is a literal, and won't do any highlighting outside the syntax highlighting.

There is a workaround available though as described in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183613/245360). You have to place your code in a `<pre><code>` block. Since Markdown supports HTML for expanded layout, this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Although not possible in Markdown a workaround is to use html.

---

Source http://meta.stackoverflow.com, answer [Highlighting parts of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260470/3536342) by [brasofilo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1287812/brasofilo)

> It's possible with HTML
>
> 1) A code block
>
> ```
> Emphasis on this
> ```
>
> ```
> <pre><code>Emphasis on <b>this</b>
> </code></pre>
> ```
>
> ---- 2) Inline code: `Emphasis on this`
>
> ```
> Inline code: <code>Emphasis on <b>this</b></code>
> ```
>
> <sub>Depending on the code, you'd need HTML entities to render it
>   ok.</sub>