# Bold or italics in Markdown inline code

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting, inline-code

I would like to add bold (or italic) text to inline code (not a block of code). So in `one **two** three`, I would like "two" to be bold rather than surrounded by asterisks.

*Note*: This is a similar question to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183610/how-to-combine-bold-and-code-sample-in-markdown). However, that question uses a code block example (not inline), and the accepted (and highest voted) answer on that page only works for code blocks.

Comment: this question is similar to [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183610/how-to-combine-bold-and-code-sample-in-markdownquestion), but I am interested in inline code, not a block of code.

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193197/388442) and [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/33523/388442) deal with inline code blocks.

Comment: @Ward I just edited my question with a note explaining why I believe my question is slightly different

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do something like

```
<code>one **two** three</code>
```

`one two three`

or

```
<code>one <b>two</b> three</code>
```

`one two three`

Answer (score 6):

It's not elegant, but it's possible: `one`**`two`**`three`.

Markdown:

```
`one `**`two`**` three`
```

(This trick works with any type of formatting.)

Comment: You can also just use `<code></code>` instead of backticks, and then any Markdown inside it will still be processed. (Note that the method in the answer loses the white space on mobile, and it all becomes one word.)